# Assign number to python from range

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm looking at a data set of scores.

I want to know the probability of each score based on the bin the score falls in using pd.cut

How can I take a value and assign it a probability based on the outputted table?

Code as follows

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'scores':[168.0, 44.0, 352.0, 128.0, 268.0, 228.0, 160.0, 376.0, 304.0, 124.0, 360.0, 36.0, 224.0, 176.0, 40.0, 28.0, 264.0, 292.0, 228.0, 80.0, 216.0, 132.0, 88.0, 220.0, 284.0, 308.0, 256.0, 360.0, 364.0, 128.0, 268.0, 72.0, 100.0, 320.0, 224.0, 300.0, 232.0, 316.0, 196.0, 248.0, 24.0, 396.0, 8.0, 248.0, 244.0, 392.0, 240.0, 28.0, 260.0, 220.0, 120.0, 56.0, 232.0, 216.0, 228.0, 232.0, 332.0, 280.0, 148.0, 84.0, 284.0, 268.0, 176.0, 324.0, 52.0, 112.0, 344.0, 296.0, 164.0, 28.0, 304.0, 344.0, 232.0, 340.0, 324.0, 248.0, 232.0, 400.0, 396.0, 36.0, 52.0, 204.0, 292.0, 96.0, 68.0, 392.0, 260.0, 224.0, 236.0, 248.0, 316.0, 292.0, 212.0, 276.0, 304.0, 124.0, 216.0, 48.0, 64.0, 228.0]})

frequencyTable = pd.cut(data['scores'], bins = 20, include_lowest=True, ordered=True, precision=4, right=False)
frequencyTable = frequencyTable.value_counts(sort=False)
frequencyTable = frequencyTable.reset_index()
frequencyTable['probability'] = frequencyTable['scores']/len(data)
print(frequencyTable)
```

Output as follows

```
               index  scores  probability
0        [8.0, 27.6)       2         0.02
1       [27.6, 47.2)       7         0.07
2       [47.2, 66.8)       5         0.05
3       [66.8, 86.4)       4         0.04
4      [86.4, 106.0)       3         0.03
5     [106.0, 125.6)       4         0.04
6     [125.6, 145.2)       3         0.03
7     [145.2, 164.8)       3         0.03
8     [164.8, 184.4)       3         0.03
9     [184.4, 204.0)       1         0.01
10    [204.0, 223.6)       7         0.07
11    [223.6, 243.2)      14         0.14
12    [243.2, 262.8)       8         0.08
13    [262.8, 282.4)       6         0.06
14    [282.4, 302.0)       7         0.07
15    [302.0, 321.6)       7         0.07
16    [321.6, 341.2)       4         0.04
17    [341.2, 360.8)       5         0.05
18    [360.8, 380.4)       2         0.02
19  [380.4, 400.392)       5         0.05
```

I'd like to be able to take input = 265 and return 6%

Comment: Given the line `3    [262.8, 282.4)       6         0.06`, wouldn't the probability be `6%` for the value `265`?

Comment: Sorry -yes; fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `frequencyTable` is a table where the first column is an `Interval` and the third column is the percentage.  So to get what you want, you iterate over the table, looking for the item where the input value (v=265) is in the `Interval` of that row, and if it is, you take the value in the third column.  So something like this:

```
v = 265
p = -1
for bin in frequencyTable.values:
    if v in bin[0]:
        p = bin[2] * 100
        break

print(p, '%')
```

Result:

```
6.0 %
```